# ANSI C++: Differences between delete and delete[]

Tags: c++

I was looking a snipset of code:

```
    int* ip;
    ip = new int[100];
    delete ip;
```

The example above states that:

> This code will work with many compilers, but it should instead read:

```
    int* ip;
    ip = new int[100];
    delete [] ip;
```

Is this indeed the case?

I use the compiler "Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 11.00.7022 for 80x86" and does not complain (first example) while compiling. At runtime the pointer is set to `NULL`.

Do other compilers behave differently? Can a compiler not complain and issues can appear at runtime?

Comment: basically I use CString (CString* pstrMyString = new CString[i];) instead of int.

Answer (score 8):

You should *always* use `delete []` when killing off an array, because it handles calling all the destructors on the contents. I think the reason why you're getting away with it here is that the `int` type doesn't have a destructor, but when you move to making arrays of objects with destructors, you'll really see the difference.

Which is a good argument for always using `std::vector` instead, of course. That gets all this stuff right for you.

Answer (score 8):

There is really no way for the compiler to produce an error in this circumstance - the type of the pointer produced by `new` and `new[]` is the same. Certainly, the C++ Standard does not require any diagnostic for this situation. However, your first code snippet is incorrect for all compilers, and will lead to undefined behaviour - don't be tempted to do it because the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: In practice, all compilers I know do the right thing, at least for simple types. Let's consider this: delete[] does not tell the compiler the size of array being deleted. Therefore, the runtime has to remember it from new[]. And if that's the case, it may as well check the size no matter what and do the right thing. I think delete[] is one of those theoretical gotchas that the language really could do without.

Comment: @Arkady Maybe it could do without it, but it's there, and writing code that ignores the fact is foolish and pointless.

Comment: @Arkady "at least for simple types" is the key. For complex types, no compiler that I know does what you say is "the right thing". G++, for example, prints "memory clobbered before allocated block" when attempted to "delete" a pointer allocated with "new[]". See http://codepad.org/uvStD4lD and http://codepad.org/e0c7ABoh .

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you MUST use `delete []` since `ip` is an array. Anyway, the compiler will never give you an error (it might give you a warning), but you can get runtime errors.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ spec requires you to use **delete []** when deleting an array, and if you're worried about cross compiler compatibility or your code working with future versions of the same compiler then you should use it.

Your runtime may choose to allocate memory differently for arrays than it does for single objects. By not correctly indicating what your deleting you run the risk that your code may fail to release memory correctly.

So, basically, call the right form...!!!